# Using trackpoint for horizontal scrolling under OS X

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, trackpoint

I have a Tex Yoda with a trackpoint.

How can I do horizontal scrolling with it under Mac OS X? It works with mouse and trackpad but with the trackpoint, only Y axis scrolling works.

Comment: What track point? What hardware? What version of OS X?

Comment: Added. Maybe there is some way to see the signals (codes) from mouse/trackpoint to determine did they send to OS or not?

Comment: Honestly, I am not aware of anything. Maybe [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/) offers an option. [Keycodes](http://manytricks.com/keycodes/) only shows key presses, not mouse movement.

Answer (score -1):

According to [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4693176) you can use either "USB overdrive" or "Smart Scroll"

Comment: This answer could really use a more detailed explanation.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.